# Android cmake link library

Tags: android, c, cmake, android-ndk

i have a folder with c (c++) files - `opus` library from telegram android open source project.
I wanna link that folder with `CMake`.
What i have - folder with source files and my own `c` file `mylib.c`.

The problem is how to include `opus` folder via CMake. If i include it like

```
include_directories(src/main/jni/opus)
link_directories(src/main/jni/opus)
```

it does not work coz some files inside `opus` folder does not see each other.
like - `app/src/main/jni/opus/src/opus.c` does not see included

```
#include "opus.h"
```

which is located in `app/src/main/jni/opus/include/opus.h`

So - how should i tune my `CMake` to force him link all files in a right way?
I can ofc manually change all files `#include` path but...

**EDIT#1**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Ofast -ffast-math")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Ofast -ffast-math")
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/jni/opus/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/jni/opus/include)
add_library(
         audio
         SHARED
         src/main/jni/audio.c)
```

Comment: Looks like a proper include directory should be `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/jni/opus/include`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev updated my full CMake. seems like include directory does not help. OR its not the only one that should be included

Comment: You need to provide CMake a directory, which contains required header file. It should be an **absolute path**. If this directory is within the project, you may use *CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR* variable for get absolute path to the project's top-level directory. So your include directory can be given as `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/<relative-dir>`. E.g., if the header file is under `src/main/jni/opus/include/` relative to the project's top-level directory, include directory may be given as `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jni/opus/include`. BTW, include directory and link directory are completely different things.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, ok i provided a ptha to all directories inside opus folder via include_directories, imports seem to be well, but now i see undefined reference error for almost every opus function.

Comment: You need to link with opus *library*. Search on Stack Overflow (or google) how to link with a library in CMake.

Comment: @TooLazy Hi, what CMake file you added opus to?